# Change view background color at some point

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/activated_item"/>
```

with style/activated_item:

```
<style name="activated_item" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/item_light_list</item>
    </style>
```

where drawable/items_light_list:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
         <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_activated_holo"></item>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected_holo_light"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected_holo_light"></item> <!-- If I would remove this line the item will be selected after a long click -->
    </selector>
```

The mentioned `LinearLayout` is used for inflating in 'view' to be used as an item(s) in `ListFragment`. I need the `android:background` value to be changed after a longpress on the item. I tried to do:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);
return true;
```

But this didn't work.

Please advice what shall I do and how to change my `drawable resourse` in order to set a different `background color` after a `longclick`.

EDIT:

If I remove `<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected_holo_light"></item>` everything is working, but this is not a  workaround for me.

Comment: Can you post any image for example? As what you want.

Comment: I want it to be just like Gmail works - when you long click on the item it changes color to green finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [View.setBackgroundColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that. Yes, I tried it, but this doesn't work if you have android:background defined in your selector. If I would remove background declaration this would work.

Comment: Another solution is to add the drawable with a color you want and set it as background after long click

Comment: Man, this really works if I use drawable. I'm shocked. I still don't understand why is that so.